# Разделение класса в заголовочный файл и в файл с кодом

Tags: c++, header, build

Вроде всегда так класс разделял в h-хедерные файлы и cpp-файлы с кодом, но в этот раз что-то пошло не так :( 
Пишет Unresolved external blablabla.obj

[Main](http://pastebin.ru/7pK6C4cZ)  [Header](http://pastebin.ru/eQeY9gON)  [CPP](http://pastebin.ru/kM0ye0NI)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я в этот раз ошибся?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема в шаблонах. Шаблоны надо размещать полностью в header'е.

Дело в том, что шаблонный класс не есть класс, и не генерирует вовсе никакого кода. Код будет сгенерирован «задним числом» в момент инстанциации шаблона, то есть, в тот момент, когда вы объявляете шаблон с конкретным параметром! (В вашем случае это `main`.) Если выгрузить имплементацию шаблона в `.cpp`, она будет в этой точке компиляции недоступна, и приведёт к ошибке компоновки.

Есть, правда, ещё один путь: если вы **точно** знаете все типы, с которыми будет когда-либо инстанциироваться шаблон, вы *можете* оставить имплементацию в `.cpp`, и добавить туда список для явной инстанциации:

```
template class Stack<char>;
```

Но это сработает только лишь если вы контролируете все места, где ваш шаблон будет использован. Если вы пишете библиотеку общего пользования, вы не можете знать наперёд, с какими типами её будут использовать клиенты, то есть этот трюк не пройдёт, и вам таки придётся писать всё в header'е. (Так работает вся STL, например.)

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [[C++ FAQ/Templates/linker errors]](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/separate-template-class-defn-from-decl.html).

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный и информативный ответ :)

Comment: @T2skler: пожалуйста!