# Использование template в C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Пытаюсь понять как использовать `template` в С++.

Как я понял, удобство `template` состоит в том, что можно использовать его как-то так:

Вместо создания 3-х методов чтения `float, int, byte` из файла:

```
void ReadFloat(){

}

void ReadInt(){

}

void ReadByte(){

}
```

Можно использовать что-то типа такого:

```
template<typename T>
T Read(){
 T s;

 file.Read(s, sizeof(T));

 return s;
}
```

Но в примерах я встречаю лишь вот такое:

```
template <class T>
class MyTemplate
{
public:
  void dump();
  T t;
};


template <class T>
void MyTemplate<T>::dump()
{
  cerr << t << endl;
}
```

И использование:

```
MyTemplate<float> m_t;

m_t.dump();
```

Но тут мне непонятно 2 вещи:

Получается, что для каждого типа данных мне нужно создавать новые объекты?

А если, к примеру, из всего класса мне нужно использовать `template` лишь к 1 методу, а не ко всему классу?

Я попробовал так:

```
class FILE_READER{
public:
    bool just_something();

    template <class T>
    T Read();

    template <class T>
    void Write(T value);
};

template<class T>

T FILE_READER::Read() {
    T value;
             // куда записывать
    ReadFile(T, sizeof(T));

    return value;
}

template<class T>

void FILE_READER::Write(T value)
{
    WriteFile(T, sizeof(T));
}

// БЕЗ template

bool FILE_READER::just_something(){
  // do something...
}
```

Как можно это реализовать правильно?

UPD: Как я прочитал в ответах, у всех прекрасно компилируется.

У меня же выдает такую ошибку:

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
> FILE_READER::Write(void)" (??$Write@H@F@@QAEXXZ) referenced in
> function _main    TM  D:\C++ Projects\TM\TM\TM.obj    1

UPD_2:

Я попробовал вставить весь этот код в 1 файл (header):

```
class FILE_READER{
public:
    bool just_something();

    template <class T>
    T Read();

    template <class T>
    void Write(T value);
};

template<class T>

T FILE_READER::Read() {
    T value;
             // куда записывать
    ReadFile(T, sizeof(T));

    return value;
}

template<class T>

void FILE_READER::Write(T value)
{
    WriteFile(T, sizeof(T));
}

// БЕЗ template

bool FILE_READER::just_something(){
  // do something...
}
```

- все заработало.

Тут же начинаю разбрасывать по .cpp и .h файлам - выдается верхняя ошибка.

test.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Test.h"

template<class T>

T FILE_READER::Read() {
    T value;
    // куда записывать
    cout << sizeof(T) << endl;

    return value;
}

template<class T>

void FILE_READER::Write(T value)
{
    cout << sizeof(T) << endl;
}

// БЕЗ template

bool FILE_READER::just_something() {
    // do something...

    return true;
}
```

test.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class FILE_READER {
public:
    bool just_something();

    template <class T>
    T Read();

    template <class T>
    void Write(T value);
};
```

Comment: Ну вот как в рамках ответа пересказать целую книгу?... :(

Comment: @Harry, без проблем. Если можно, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, книгу, я не хочу решить "так чтобы вот работало и нормально", я хочу детально в этом разобраться

Comment: На будущее, если с кодом в вопросе какие-то проблемы, то сразу говорите какие. А то пишете *"Я попробовал так: [код] Как можно это реализовать правильно?"* и непонятно, что с кодом не так. Не компилируется? Компилируется, но не уверены, что сделали все правильно?

Comment: Ну, книгу то посоветовать несложно - Ваневурд, Джосаттис, Грегор "Шаблоны С++" Второе издание. Но для начинающего, пожалуй, слишком сложновата. Хотя определенные главы вполне доступны. Жаль, не помню, где шаблоны излагаются на простом уровне - но посмотрите в Интернете, [материалов много](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B+%D0%A1%2B%2B+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:unofficial)

Comment: Обновил ответ под новые правки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Можно использовать что-то типа такого:
>
> ```
> template<typename T>
> T Read(){
>  T s;
>
>  file.Read(s, sizeof(T));
>
>  return s;
> }
> ```

Так используйте, почему нет.

> Но в примерах я встречаю лишь вот такое: [шаблон класса]

Значит, мало примеров посмотрели. Бывают шаблоны функций (как у вас), бывают шаблоны классов (как в ваших примерах). Даже шаблоны переменных бывают.

> ```
> MyTemplate<float> m_t;
>
> m_t.dump();
> ```
>
> Получается, что для каждого типа данных мне нужно создавать новые
>   объекты?

Да. Но их иожно делать временными!

```
MyTemplate<float>{}.dump();
```

> А если, к примеру, из всего класса мне нужно использовать template
>   лишь к 1 методу, а не ко всему классу?
>
> Я попробовал так: [код]

Все правильно пробовали. У меня этот код компилируется.

---

> UPD_2:
>
> Я попробовал вставить весь этот код в 1 файл (header) - все заработало.
>
> Тут же начинаю разбрасывать по cpp и h файлам - выдается
>
> ```
> LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall FILE_READER::Write(void)" (??$Write@H@F@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main TM D:\C++ Projects\TM\TM\TM.obj 1
> ```

Ну это классика. Определения шаблонов должны быть в хедерах (кроме особых случаев).

Раз: [Разделение класса в заголовочный файл и в файл с кодом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/381702/215103)

Два: [Не работает обьявление шаблона класса в заголовочном файле с определением методов в отдельном файле реализации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937440/)

И так далее.